# What is the word "spirituality" derived from?

Tags: historical-linguistics, origin-of-language

What is the word spirtuality or spirit derived from?

Is it's origin based on the Christian idea of the Holy Ghost, or perhaps something earlier, like how the Greeks and Romans believed in spirits?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried a thesaurus and Wikipedia? If yes, can you report what information was missing in these sources and make that clear in your question?

Comment: This is off topic. You could perhaps ask on the English Learners site (because it is offtopic at English too.)

Comment: Etymology is actually on topic, but like Robert said, what have you searched and what have you found?

Comment: @curiousdannii But it would be off-topic on ELL…

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered by looking it up in commonly used resources.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had tried looking it up on a dictionary and britanica online but hadn't found any satisfactory answers (the oldest reference was from the late 1800s but I was sure that the word must have been older than that

Comment: The fact that "Holy Spirit" is a compound shows you that it can't be the original sense of the word. In general what words refer to don't define the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a fairly good source to answer questions on English etymology:

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spiritual&searchmode=none